# No consigo visualizar la barra de la libreria DEBUGBAR en laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

He instalado esta libreria barryvdh/laravel-debugbar en laravel 5.4.36
y no consigo que se visualice, he añadido en config/app en el apartado de service provider esta linea

```
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
```

y en el apartado de facades esta otra linea

```
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
```

He hecho un composer dumpautoload  y como no me funcionaba he probado a bajar la version del debugbar a la 2.3.2 y el mismo resultado.

también he probado estos dos comandos

```
 php artisan cache:clear 

 php artisan config:cache
```

y en el archivo ENV, tengo estas dos lineas con estos valores

```
APP_ENV = local
APP_DEBUG = true
```

y sigo sin poder visualizar la barra, se me acaban las opciones, no sé que mas probar, no consigo visualizar la barra, no da ningún tipo de error, ni escrito ni grafico, todo se muestra como si la barra estuviese desactivada, lo he probado en firefox y en chrome y nada.
He instalado y desinstalado varias versiones usando composer require y también editando directamente el archivo composer.json(creo que es lo mismo que el composer require) y sigue sin aparecer

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: has instalado con `composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:~2.4`?? y con `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"`??

Comment: probados ambos comandos y sigue sin funcionar, probado también con  este comando
composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar:~2.4 --dev
y lo mismo.

Answer (score 1):

Te parecera raro pero necesitas evitar cache de la siguiente forma:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan debugbar:clear
```

y ahora entra en navegación privada.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza este comando:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Nada, sigue sin funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Doc. primero tienes que agregar en composer.json la libreria a usar o escribir en el command dentro de tu carpeta de tu app:

1-  composer require barryvdh/laravel-debugbar --dev

2-  agregar en config/app.php

```
Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,
'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,
```

3- en .env actia el debug poniendo en ( debug = true)

4- por si acaso termina escribiendo en el command: composer update

Comment: Por si no te fijaste, todos esos pasos ya fueron realizados.

Comment: alguna vez me paso que al descargar un proyecto nuevo no descargo bien algunas cosas y tuve que crear un nuevo proyecto y pasar lo que ya había avanzado. te recomendaria q hagas una nueva descarga de laravel 5.4